# How can I delete special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm practicing with Ruby and regex to delete certain unwanted characters. For example:

```
input = input.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, '')
```

and for special characters, example ☻ or ™:

```
input = input.gsub('&#', '')
```

This leaves only numbers, ok. But this only works if the user enters a special character as a code, like this:

```
&#153;
```

**My question:**
How I can delete special characters if the user enters a special character without code, like this:

```
™ ☻
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

First of all, I think it might be easier to define what constitutes "correct input" and remove everything else. For example:

```
input = input.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

If that's not what you want (you want to support non-latin alphabets, etc.), then I think you should make a list of the glyphs you want to remove (like ™ or ☻), and remove them one-by-one, since it's hard to distinguish between a Chinese, Arabic, etc. character and a pictograph programmatically.

Finally, you might want to normalize your input by converting to or from HTML escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I think is easier to create a list of allowed characters.

Comment: Thanks!! I've used `input = input.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ')` to keep the string as is. It does give me some extra spaces at the place of  these special chars.

Answer (score 10):

If you just wanted ASCII characters, then you can use:

```
original = "aøbauhrhræoeuacå" 
cleaned = ""
original.each_byte { |x|  cleaned << x unless x > 127   }
cleaned   # => "abauhrhroeuac"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can match all the characters you want, and then join them together, like this:

```
original = "aøbæcå"
stripped = original.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/).to_s
puts stripped
```

which outputs `"abc"`

Answer (score 9):

You can use [parameterize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize):

```
'@!#$%^&*()111'.parameterize
 => "111"
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Gotcha with parameterize: It leaves dashes. I use 'something-here'.underscore.parameterize to account for it.

Comment: You can pass a custom separator to parameterize: `string.parameterize(separator: '_')`

Answer (score 5):

An easier way to do this inspirated by Can Berk Güder answer is:

In order to delete special characters:

```
input = input.gsub(/\W/, '')
```

In order to keep word characters:

```
input = input.scan(/\w/)
```

At the end input is the same! Try it on : http://rubular.com/