# Remove all non-alphabetical, non-numerical characters from a string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

If I wanted to remove things like:
.!,'"^-# from an array of strings, how would I go about this while retaining all alphabetical and numeric characters.

Allowed alphabetical characters should also include letters with diacritical marks including à or ç.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737475/how-i-can-delete-special-characters this will answer 50% of your question

Comment: Normally we talk about a String having characters and an Array having  different data, e.g. objects, numbers, or strings. Do you really have an Array (perhaps an array of strings?) or just a String?

Comment: -1. Not so much for not trying to work it out, but because the question is nonsensical for the reason given by Phrogz.

Comment: A hash of arrays of strings. Nice. (What?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use a regex with the correct character property. In this case, you can invert the `Alnum` class (Alphabetic and numeric character):

```
"◊¡ Marc-André !◊".gsub(/\p{^Alnum}/, '') # => "MarcAndré"
```

For more complex cases, say you wanted also punctuation, you can also build a set of acceptable characters like:

```
"◊¡ Marc-André !◊".gsub(/[^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]/, '') # => "¡MarcAndré!"
```

For all character properties, you can refer to the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

Comment: Note that you're answering how to gsub on a string, but the title and description use the word "array".

Comment: @Phrogz: Indeed. Hopefully the OP knows how to do a `map`.

Answer (score 3):

```
string.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, "")
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will work for an `array`:

```
z = ['asfdå', 'b12398!', 'c98347']
z.each { |s| s.gsub! /[^[:alnum:]]/, '' }
puts z.inspect
```

I borrowed Jeremy's suggested `regex`.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, I totally missed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a regular expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

I'm assuming that you're using ruby since you tagged that in your post. You could go through the array, put it through a test using a regexp, and if it passes remove/keep it based on the regexp you use.

A regexp you might use might go something like this:

```
[^.!,^-#]
```

That will tell you if its **not** one of the characters inside the brackets. However, I suggest that you look up regular expressions, you might find a better solution once you know their syntax and usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have an array (as you state) and it is an array of strings (I'm guessing), e.g.

```
foo = [ "hello", "42 cats!", "yöwza" ]
```

then I can imagine that you either want to update each string in the array with a new value, or that you want a modified array that only contains certain strings.

If the former (you want to 'clean' every string the array) you could do one of the following:

```
foo.each{ |s| s.gsub! /\p{^Alnum}/, '' }     # Change every string in place…
bar = foo.map{ |s| s.gsub /\p{^Alnum}/, '' } # …or make an array of new strings
#=> [ "hello", "42cats", "yöwza" ]
```

If the latter (you want to select a subset of the strings where each matches your criteria of holding only alphanumerics) you could use one of these:

```
# Select only those strings that contain ONLY alphanumerics
bar = foo.select{ |s| s =~ /\A\p{Alnum}+\z/ }
#=> [ "hello", "yöwza" ]

# Shorthand method for the same thing
bar = foo.grep /\A\p{Alnum}+\z/     
#=> [ "hello", "yöwza" ]
```

In Ruby, regular expressions of the form `/\A………\z/` require the entire string to match, as `\A` anchors the regular expression to the start of the string and `\z` anchors to the end.